# ASP.NET: Save if the user is logged in

Tags: asp.net, authentication, razor

I just wanted to ask if it is possible to save a boolean to see if a user is currently logged in WITHOUT a cookie? I read about Identity in ASP.NET, but how does it save the whole data? In the database? And then I also ask myself if it would be good practice to just save the boolean in my own database to know if the user is logged in. Or is this bad practice?

I think it is obvious that this is my first time creating a login functionality. I already read a lot of articles of microsoft and other third party sites. They are all talking about Identity and Cookies, but I am just curious if it is possible otherwise. For instance with my own database.

Thank you for every answer.

Comment: Sure, it's possible to do without cookies. However, you need some way of identifying that a client is who they say they are. In the stateless web, we have to build state on top of it. That means the client has got to provide some sort of indication in each request that we can verify if we want to probably consider them authenticated. A cookie is one way, another way would be to append an HTTP header to your requests (that's pretty much what a cookie is anyways) or even to include that information in the URL (which has problems, so don't do that) or in the body of the request.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid cookies? What's the issue you have with them?

Comment: I am currently read through the laws of cookies. I don't want to use cookies because I want to avoid a cookies policy/dialog. However, I think Cookies is the best way to save the information. Nevertheless, thank you for your comment. Do you know if I need a cookies dialog for essential cookies in the EU? Maybe I should ask another question on another site, but maybe you know it.

Comment: I am not familiar with the EU data privacy laws, as they don't apply to the applications I work on. And asking about legal requirements on Stack Overflow isn't on-topic, as it's not a practical programming problem and it deals with legalities that we aren't set up to deal with. Perhaps our sister site, the [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for that question if you're unable to find out yourself after research.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought so. Thank you for your answers!